# Get IDs from all files of a folder

Tags: document-library, rest

I use `.../lists/getbytitle('rootFolderName')/items(11575)` (where **11575** is the id of a file) to update the data of a file and it works fine. Now, I want to call this for all files inside a folder. So I thought I try to get all their IDs and then I would run this in a loop.

I tried `.../GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('DocLib/FolderName')/Files` but the ids that it returns are like

```
<entry>
<id>Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('.../DocLib/FolderName/_DSC5603.jpg')</id>
...
</entry>
```

Which is correct but I would expect an integer, like **11575**. Is there any way to get the IDs of those files? If this isn't possible, can I find this information from the database maybe?

Comment: you need to expand fields as shown below
.../GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('DocLib/FolderName')/Files?$select=*,ListItemAllFields/Id,ListItemAllFields/Created,FileRef&$expand=ListItemAllFields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('DocLib/FolderName')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Comment: Can't I get all ids with one call? If I were to use `ListItemAllFields` I would have to first find all filenames of the folder's files, I guess I can do that but that's an extra step.

Comment: Yep, try edited code